# How to create Google Cloud AI Platform Notebook from snapshot?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I have a Google Cloud AI Platform Notebook that I believe ran out of disk space.
I attempted to delete some files, and stopped the Notebook instance.  However, I could no longer launch the notebook (504 error). 
Assuming the Notebook instance was corrupt, I attempted to create a new Notebook instance using a snapshot of an earlier version of the original Notebook. I thought I was safe creating snapshots as a backup.

Unfortunately, I can find no option to specify the boot disk from the snapshot when launching a new Notebook (Note: this option is available for other compute instances).

Big problem if you want to restore a Notebook from an earlier version via a snapshot.

Is there any way to create Google Cloud AI Platform Notebook from a snapshot?

Any direction would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: If you still get 504 Error, try to login via SSH and run: `/opt/c2d/scripts/04-attempt-register-vm-on-proxy.sh` also would be nice if you can post the Serial Log port output.

Comment: As I indicated, I can not start the old instance let along SSH into it. What I would like to do is create a new notebook instance from a saved snapshot. Thanks.

Comment: Got it, sometimes the 504 error you can still ssh. Will give you instructions.

Comment: gogasca - you were right. I was trying to ssh via the notebook interface. If you ssh in via the VM it works. Thanks.